# Access data from a vue array element when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js, vue-component

My vue data consists of a list of people.

```
self.vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-div",
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    unsafeDelimiters: ['!{', '}'],
    data: {
        users: [
            {first_name: "John",
             last_name: "Doe",
             email: "jdoe@gmail.com"
            },
            {first_name: "Jane",
             last_name: "Smith",
             email: "jsmith@gmail.com"
            },
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        test: function(e) {
            alert(this.users[0].email);

        }
    }

});
```

I then display the names of those people in a list using v-for:

```
<ul v-for="user in users">
    <li class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="test">${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}</li>
</ul>
```

currently, in order to alert the actual email of a user in the array, I have to hardcode an index to be alerted.  My question is, how do I dynamically access the data of the array element that has been clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to get the index while rendering the array elements, and then passing that index to a function.

I could then look up the element in the array and alert the email

```
<ul v-for="(user, index) in users">
    <li v-on:click="test(index)">${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}</li>
</ul>

self.test = function(index) {
   alert(self.vue.users[index].email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the email to the `test` function in the template:

`v-on:click="test(user.email)"`

And then:

```
function test(email) {
    alert(email);
}
```